# Temporarily using a different protocol with remote repository

Tags: git, version-control, git-remote, git-fetch, git-config

I've on my laptop a git repository, and a remote repository on GiHub (a straight forward configuration created when running 'git clone').

I'm using the SSH transfer protocol. i.e. remote address is: git@github.com:MyName/MyProg.git

I'm now in a network environment where port 23 is blocked (As far as I can see, only ports 80 and 443 are open). I need to fetch/merge recent changes available on the server. What are my options? If possible, I'd like to avoid creating a new remote branch with the http protocol (which is basically identical to the remote branch I already have).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change url of the origin:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/MyName/MyProg.git
```

and work as usual. Then change it back if port unblocked.

Second approach. You could change port which ssh uses by its config. github also provides ssh connection via port 443. For this you need to create a file `~/.ssh/config` with the following content:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

For debugging you could use `ssh -v git@github.com`.

BTW, ssh port is number 22, not 23.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change the url in the `.git/config` file to the one you want by editing the file directly or by using `git config` or `git remote set-url`.

But you would not need to create a new remote branch. What you meant is that you did not want another remote *tracking* branch; the above would do the trick.

Having another remote pointing to an alternate url is just fine. You can add it this way:

```
git remote add alternate https://github.com/account/repo.git
```

There is no inefficiency that it brings. So instead of doing

```
git fetch
```

you now will specify which one with

```
git fetch origin
```

or

```
git fetch alternate
```

You can give remotes whatever names you want.

same thing with `git push`. You can specify to the degree you want and setup defaults if you don't specify.

Answer (score 0):

### Add New Remote for Alternate Protocol

You can have multiple remotes for a repository. You can add an alternative remote with a different URI scheme, even if it points to the same underlying repository. For example, to pull from a remote named "alternate" into your master branch:

```
git remote add alternate https://github.com/MyName/MyProg.git
git checkout master
git pull alternate master
```

Since the underlying repository is the same, this should not have any impact on your history. History will be the same whether you use the SSH or HTTPS protocols.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using pull. It is 2 commands in one. Do fetch first then merge or rebase or something else based on what was fetched. Pull is ok only in cases when you're usually working alone and you are simply updating another computer you're working from or some similar simple scenario. I would not recommend it as the default go-to workflow.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk Pull vs. fetch/merge has nothing to do with the OP's question. The question is about URI schemes, and I'm confident that my answer illustrates that use case quite well since you incorporated my answer into yours. However, please feel free to use whatever merging work-flow suits you better if you don't like the use of [git-pull](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html).

Comment: hence it's in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Without adding the temporary remote, you can fetch from a temporary target as follows

```
git fetch https://mytoken@github.com/<username>/<repo.git> master:remotes/origin/master
```

Which will update `origin/master` refspec from the master branch on the that temp remote url.